# Adding additional play buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Can I place 2 additional play buttons on here?

Is this possible to do?
https://jsfiddle.net/hk4dvj15/2/

I would like to place 2 additional play buttons inside those 2 empty squares, how would I do this?

I was told I can do this, but I have no idea how I would set this up.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xbQMLsj.png]

```
  <div id="playButton2" style="width: 260px;height:44px;background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px );border: 3px solid #0059dd; cursor: pointer;" onclick=" 
            var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
            var player = document.getElementById('player2');
              document.querySelector('#playButton2 .initial').style.display='none';
              document.querySelector('#playButton2 .speaker').style.display='none';
              document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='none';
            player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
            document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
            document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='none';
            player.play();
            } else {
            document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='none';
            document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='inline-block';
            player.pause();
            }" onmouseover="
    var player = document.getElementById('player2');
    player.isPlaying = function () {
        return player.paused === false;
    }
    if  (player.isPlaying()) {
      document.querySelector('#playButton2 .speaker').style.display='none';
      document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
    }"

    onmouseout="
    var player = document.getElementById('player2');
    player.isPlaying = function () {
        return player.paused === false;
    }
    if  (player.isPlaying()) {
      document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='none';
      document.querySelector('#playButton2 .speaker').style.display='inline-block';
    }">


     <svg class="initial" style="margin:15px 124px;" width="12" height="14" viewBox="0 0 85 100"><path fill="white" d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path></svg>

    <svg class="pause" style="display: none;margin:15px 125px;" width="10" height="14" viewBox="0 0 60 100"><path fill="#1ed760" d="M0 8c0-5 3-8 8-8s9 3 9 8v84c0 5-4 8-9 8s-8-3-8-8V8zm43 0c0-5 3-8 8-8s8 3 8 8v84c0 5-3 8-8 8s-8-3-8-8V8z"></path></svg>

    <svg  class="speaker" style="display: none;margin:15px 122px;" width="16" height="14" viewBox="0 0 16 14"><path d="M12.945.38l-.652.762c1.577 1.462 2.57 3.544 2.57 5.858 0 2.314-.994 4.396-2.57 5.858l.65.763c1.79-1.644 2.92-3.997 2.92-6.62S14.735 2.024 12.945.38zm-2.272 2.66l-.65.762c.826.815 1.34 1.947 1.34 3.198 0 1.25-.515 2.382-1.342 3.2l.652.762c1.04-1 1.69-2.404 1.69-3.96 0-1.558-.65-2.963-1.69-3.963zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z" fill="#1ed760" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>

    <svg class="play" style="display: none;margin:15px 124px;" width="12" height="14" viewBox="0 0 85 100"><path fill="#1ed760" d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path></svg>

    </div>

    <audio id="player2" style="display:none;">
      <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
    </audio>
```

Comment: I would recommend you place your `javascript` into a script tag to help clean up the source code and make it easier to work with. inline script are okay if you only wish to execute a something small or a function. This work fix your problem but will make things better to work with and will no doubt enable you from copy/pasting duplicate functions/scripts.

Comment: You mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3dzLwybx/1/

Comment: Yes, that is much better and easier to read/work with but I see you have managed to place 2 additional play buttons so no answer or solution can be posted for this question :)